# Python def not changing values of integers

Tags: python

I made a def which is supposed to add 1 to an integer, but it doesn't.

```
import ssd1306
import machine
from machine import Pin
import time
import uos
import machine

ez = 0
r = 0
e = 8
nah = 10
erg = 10

WIDTH = 128
HEIGHT = 64
i2c = machine.I2C(0)

def ereter(ez, r, e):
    ez+=1
    print(ez)
    oled.fill(0)
    oled.text("{}".format(ez), 35, 10)
    oled.text(":{}".format(r), 50, 10)
    oled.text(":{}".format(e), 72, 10)
    oled.text("The time is ^ rn", 0, 30)
    oled.text("i2c devices:"+str(i2c.scan()), 0, 40)
    oled.show()
    if ez>58: r+=1
    if ez>58: ez-=60
    if r>58: e+=1
    if r>58: r-=60
    if e>11: e-=12

while nah>1:
    ereter(ez, r, e)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I was expecting the code to add 1 to ez every second, but instead, it just doesn't change the value of ez.

Comment: integers are immutable... the value of the (global) `ez` will always be `0`. you could move `ez =+ 1` into the `while` loop - before calling the `ereter` function.

Comment: Or, as you also seem to want other variables to be mutable, you could introduce a class; make ez, r and e members - and eliminate them as both global variables and arguments to ereter - which would need to be a method.  You could also solve it using nonlocal instead of passing these global variables (by value) as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You know inside functions all global variables (variables that is defined above after modules) are rewrited. To solve this problem maybe you should add `global` key after def key. It should look like this:

```py
def ereter(ez, r, e):
    global ez
    ez+=1
    # continue of function
```

Comment: Using a return value would be a better solution, as using `global` leads to inflexible and error-prone code.

Comment: @Matthias Yeah I thought so after I published my answer. Thank u

Comment: Hey, can you edit your code and make it so that you're using a return value and not global? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I used your code and I got the error "identifier redefined as global"